Remove "Chapter" for some chapter in TOC memoir (some chapters after no adding to TOC)
I have a trouble with adding to TOC some unnumbered chapters and removing Chapter #1 for some chapters in memoir class... I need to create my custom chapter styles, based on bianchi.
For example, I want that Intro added to TOC, and for Bibliography Chapter #1 keyword be removed...
Now:
Chapter Intro
Chapter 1. Blabla
.
.
.

Chapter Bibliography

And I want to set:
Intro
Chapter 1. Blabla
.
.
.
Bibliography

How to solve this problem?
\begin{filecontents}{thebib.bib}
@misc{mathworks_constant_2018,
    type = {Documentation},
    title = {Constant volume pneumatic chamber based on ideal gas law},
    url = {https://uk.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/ref/constantvolumepneumaticchamber.html},
    urldate = {2022-01-01},
    journal = {Mathworks Simulink Documentation},
    author = {{Mathworks}},
    year = {2018},
}

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4papper, twoside, 14pt, openany]{memoir}

\makechapterstyle{test}{%
  \chapterstyle{bianchi}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{%
    \normalfont\Huge\bfseries\sffamily}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{%
    \normalfont\Huge\bfseries\sffamily}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}%
  \setlength\beforechapskip{-6pt} % not the same as no space above
                                % because of \vspace* internally
  \setlength\afterchapskip{1.5\baselineskip}
  \setlength\midchapskip{20pt}
}

\makechapterstyle{bianchi-no-lines}{
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\sffamily}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\sffamily}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries\sffamily}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{\chapnamefont \chapname}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{
    \centering \chapnumfont \thechapter \space
  }
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{
    \centering \chaptitlefont ##1
  }
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{\vphantom{\chapnumfont 1\quad}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchapternum}{}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\par\nobreak\vskip 20pt}
  \renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace*{\beforechapskip}}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\vskip \afterchapskip}
}

\renewcommand{\cftchapteraftersnum}{.}
\setsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\bfseries\sffamily}
\renewcommand\cftsectionaftersnum{.\space}
\renewcommand\cftsubsectionaftersnum{.\space}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
   top=20mm, bottom=20mm,
   headheight=\baselineskip, % стандартный отступ по размеру <<клея>>
   headsep=2mm,
   footskip=8mm,      
}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\renewcommand\cftchaptername{\chaptername~}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{12pt} %reduces spacing between titles
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{1em}     %indent titles 1em, allow 0em for numbers
\renewcommand{\cftchapterpresnum}{\hspace{0.em}}

\addbibresource{thebib.bib}

\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}

\renewcommand{\cftchapterleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname\space}

\defbibheading{bibliography}[\bibname]{%  
 \chapter*{#1}%   
 \markboth{#1}{#1}   
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\chapternumberline{}#1} }

\begin{document}

\chapterstyle{bianchi-no-lines}
\begin{center}
\tableofcontents*
\end{center}


\chapterstyle{bianchi-no-lines}
\chapter*{Intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Intro}
\lipsum[1-2]

\chapterstyle{test}

\chapter{blablabla}

\lipsum[1-6]

\section{blablabla}

\lipsum[1-4]

\subsection{blablabla}

\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter{blavla}

\lipsum[1-2]

\section{blablabla}

\lipsum[1-6]

\subsection{blablabla}

\lipsum[1]

\newpage

\addtocontents{toc}{\setlength{\cftchapterindent}{0.0em}}
\chapterstyle{bianchi-no-lines}
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]
\end{document}


And you think giving us a bib file will help us fix your problem?

@daleif
Sorry, I edit post, add some detail. I just attached the full file to avoid the problem of a bibliography of several pages.

Note that tocloft does nothing with memoir, which has its own equivalent

Why do you have \protect\chapternumberline{} in the bibheading setting? That is where the \cftchaptername gets added to the number. You do not need it here.

@daleif
Indeed, I can delete this code here... I use tocloft for some comands for formatting toc -- there are solutions from another posts...

Memoir has tocloft build in (almost identical copy, it also has its own equivalent of geometry, though not key-val based)
